# Texture the quad with different parts of texture

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, directx11

I have a 2D quad. Let say it's position is (5,10) and size is (7,11).

I want to texture it with one texture, but using three different parts of it.
I want to texture the part of quad from x = 5 to x = 7 with part of texture from U = 0 to U = 0.5 (replaying it after achieving 0.5, so I will have 4 same 0.5-lenght fragments).
The second one with some other part of texture (also repeating it) and third in the same style.

But, how to achieve it?

I know that:

```
float2 tc = fmod(input.TexCoord, textureCoordinates.zw - textureCoordinates.xy) + textureCoordinates.xy; //textureCoordinates.xy = fragments' offset
```

Will give me the texture part replaying.

Comment: You need a vertex for a texture coordinate. You can't apply texture coordinates mid-triangle (as far as I know). Just break your quad into smaller quads, or make a new texture that matches your desired output.

Comment: You could also use some kind of weird shader, but breaking it into multiple quads seems like the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to break the quad into multiple smaller quads. You'll need a to input a coordinate for the texture, and the easiest way to do that is with a vertex.